# Create new variable with other variables on base of another variable

Tags: r

I have 4 date variables and 1 grouping variable. Based on the value in the grouping variable a date needs to be taken into a new variable.
My data looks like this: (https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlfv89qc1jzwfgk/vb.JPG)

I want to make a new variable based on the value of group. When group is A I need date1, when group is B I need date2, etc.

This is the code I've used:

```
if (tabel$group == A) {
  newvar <- tabel$date1
} else if (tabel$group == B) {
  newvar <- tabel$date2
} else if (tabel$group == C) {
  newvar <- tabel$date3
} else if (tabel$group == D) {
  newvar <- tabel$date4
}
```

This code give me a warning message:

*(In if (tabel$group == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data (not a picture of it) and all necessary code. You probably want `ifelse` or `dplyr::case_when`, since `if`/`else` structures aren't vectorized. Several SO questions deal with this warning

Comment: If I execute your code as posted I get the error message *Error: object 'A' not found*. How is variable `A` defined, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform this row-wise...one option is to use nested `ifelse()`

```
newvar=ifelse(tabel$group=='A',tabel$date1,
              ifelse(tabel$group=='B',tabel$date2,
                     ifelse(tabel$group=='C',tabel$date3,tabel$date4))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this has been asked and answered several times before but I haven't found a good duplicate.

Nested `ifelse()` aren't always the best solution. It is cumbersome to code, read and maintain with lots of parentheses. Furthermore, `ifelse()` may change the type of the result unexpectedly, e.g., class `Date`.

So, I want to post some alternatives

#### Subsetting using `match()`

This one uses the specific fact that the first letter "A" corresponds to the first date column `date1`, etc. So, it may not be applicable in general:

```
indices <- matrix(c(seq.int(nrow(tabel)), match(tabel$group, LETTERS[1:4])), ncol = 2)
newvar <- tabel[, -1][indices]
newvar
```

> ```
>  [1] "2011-01-01" "2011-01-02" "2011-01-03" "2012-02-04" "2012-02-05" "2012-02-06" "2013-03-07" "2013-03-08" "2013-03-09"
> [10] "2014-04-10" "2014-04-11" "2014-04-12"
> ```

The `indices` (row number, column number) which are used for subsetting are:

> ```
>       [,1] [,2]
>  [1,]    1    1
>  [2,]    2    1
>  [3,]    3    1
>  [4,]    4    2
>  [5,]    5    2
>  [6,]    6    2
>  [7,]    7    3
>  [8,]    8    3
>  [9,]    9    3
> [10,]   10    4
> [11,]   11    4
> [12,]   12    4
> ```

`tabel[, -1]` omits the first column (`group`).

#### `case_when()`

This is avectorised version of multiple `if_else()` statements from the `dplyr` package.

```
newvar <- dplyr::case_when(
  tabel$group == "A" ~ tabel$date1,
  tabel$group == "B" ~ tabel$date2,
  tabel$group == "C" ~ tabel$date3,
  tabel$group == "D" ~ tabel$date4)
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
newvar <- tabel %>% 
  transmute(value = case_when(group == "A" ~ date1,
                              group == "B" ~ date2,
                              group == "C" ~ date3,
                              group == "D" ~ date4)) %>% 
  pull(value)
```

#### Joining with a look-up table using `data.table`

Look-up tables treat the relation between `group` and column name as data and thus are easy to create and maintain. On the other hand, `tabel` has to be reshaped from wide to long format before it can be joined with `lookup`:

```
library(data.table)
lookup <- data.table(group = LETTERS[1:4], variable = paste0("date", 1:4))
newvar <- melt(setDT(tabel), id.vars = "group")[lookup, on = .(group, variable)]$value

lookup
```

> ```
>    group variable
> 1:     A    date1
> 2:     B    date2
> 3:     C    date3
> 4:     D    date4
> ```

The reshaped long format is

```
melt(setDT(tabel), id.vars = "group")
```

> ```
>     group variable      value
>  1:     A    date1 2011-01-01
>  2:     A    date1 2011-01-02
>  3:     A    date1 2011-01-03
>  4:     B    date1 2011-01-04
>  5:     B    date1 2011-01-05
>  6:     B    date1 2011-01-06
>  7:     C    date1 2011-01-07
>  8:     C    date1 2011-01-08
>  9:     C    date1 2011-01-09
> 10:     D    date1 2011-01-10
> 11:     D    date1 2011-01-11
> 12:     D    date1 2011-01-12
> 13:     A    date2 2012-02-01
> 14:     A    date2 2012-02-02
> 15:     A    date2 2012-02-03
> 16:     B    date2 2012-02-04
> 17:     B    date2 2012-02-05
> 18:     B    date2 2012-02-06
> 19:     C    date2 2012-02-07
> 20:     C    date2 2012-02-08
> 21:     C    date2 2012-02-09
> 22:     D    date2 2012-02-10
> 23:     D    date2 2012-02-11
> 24:     D    date2 2012-02-12
> 25:     A    date3 2013-03-01
> 26:     A    date3 2013-03-02
> 27:     A    date3 2013-03-03
> 28:     B    date3 2013-03-04
> 29:     B    date3 2013-03-05
> 30:     B    date3 2013-03-06
> 31:     C    date3 2013-03-07
> 32:     C    date3 2013-03-08
> 33:     C    date3 2013-03-09
> 34:     D    date3 2013-03-10
> 35:     D    date3 2013-03-11
> 36:     D    date3 2013-03-12
> 37:     A    date4 2014-04-01
> 38:     A    date4 2014-04-02
> 39:     A    date4 2014-04-03
> 40:     B    date4 2014-04-04
> 41:     B    date4 2014-04-05
> 42:     B    date4 2014-04-06
> 43:     C    date4 2014-04-07
> 44:     C    date4 2014-04-08
> 45:     C    date4 2014-04-09
> 46:     D    date4 2014-04-10
> 47:     D    date4 2014-04-11
> 48:     D    date4 2014-04-12
>     group variable      value
> ```

#### Joining with a look-up table using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
lookup <- tibble(group = LETTERS[1:4], key = paste0("date", 1:4))
newvar <- tabel %>% 
  gather(key, value, -group) %>% 
  inner_join(lookup) %>% 
  pull(value)
```

This works as above: create look-up table, reshape from wide to long format and join. `pull()` returns a simple result vector.

#### Reproducible data

```
tabel <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 3L),
                    date1 = as.Date("2011-01-01") + 0:11,
                    date2 = as.Date("2012-02-01") + 0:11,
                    date3 = as.Date("2013-03-01") + 0:11,
                    date4 = as.Date("2014-04-01") + 0:11)
tabel
```

> ```
>     group      date1      date2      date3      date4
>  1:     A 2011-01-01 2012-02-01 2013-03-01 2014-04-01
>  2:     A 2011-01-02 2012-02-02 2013-03-02 2014-04-02
>  3:     A 2011-01-03 2012-02-03 2013-03-03 2014-04-03
>  4:     B 2011-01-04 2012-02-04 2013-03-04 2014-04-04
>  5:     B 2011-01-05 2012-02-05 2013-03-05 2014-04-05
>  6:     B 2011-01-06 2012-02-06 2013-03-06 2014-04-06
>  7:     C 2011-01-07 2012-02-07 2013-03-07 2014-04-07
>  8:     C 2011-01-08 2012-02-08 2013-03-08 2014-04-08
>  9:     C 2011-01-09 2012-02-09 2013-03-09 2014-04-09
> 10:     D 2011-01-10 2012-02-10 2013-03-10 2014-04-10
> 11:     D 2011-01-11 2012-02-11 2013-03-11 2014-04-11
> 12:     D 2011-01-12 2012-02-12 2013-03-12 2014-04-12
> ```